# Different number floating point number between lua and javascript

Tags: lua, precision, floating-accuracy

Why in lua the following computation is

```
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(6.4620332164+14)
20.4620332164
```

While in Javascript

```
console.log(6.4620332164+14)
VM208:1 20.462033216400002
```

or python its

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
>>> print(6.4620332164+14)
20.462033216400002
```

What is special about the lua floating point number implementation here assuming they are all double precision IEE 754?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` calls `tostring` on each argument.

```
> print(20.462033216400002)
20.4620332164
```

So, try

```
> print(string.format("%2.15f", 20.462033216400002))
20.462033216400002
```

Simply IEEE-754 doubles.